# sorting a struct array

Tags: c, sorting

I read a text file and stored the data in a `struct` array, then tried to sort it and to print the un-sorted and sorted arrays.  It works up to reading the array text and storing in the array, but the sorting function does not run without giving any errors. what is wrong with it? I used the `strcmp()` function to compare `student[s]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct person { //struct person with 4 fields
    char name[100];
    char address[100];
    char IDnumber[20];
    int  age;
};

int main (void) {
    FILE *file = fopen ( "personout.txt", "r");
    struct person student[10]; // declares an struct array to store data
    int k = 0;
    if (file != NULL) {
        char line[300];
        while ( k < 10 && fgets ( line, sizeof line, file ) != NULL ) {
            if ( 4 == sscanf ( line, " %99[^,], %99[^,], %19[^,], %d", 
                student[k].name, student[k].address, student[k].IDnumber, &student[k].age))
            {
                printf ( "%s\n Un-sorted array");
                printf ( "%s\n", student[k].name);
                printf ( "%s\n", student[k].address);
                printf ( "%s\n", student[k].IDnumber);
                printf ( "%d\n", student[k].age);
                k++;
            }
        }
        fclose ( file );
    }
    sortarray();

    // prints sorted array
    printf ( "%s\n Sorted array");
    for (int t=0;t<10;t++) {
        printf ( "%s\n", student[t].name);
        printf ( "%s\n", student[t].address);
        printf ( "%s\n", student[t].IDnumber);
        printf ( "%d\n", student[t].age);
        t++;
    }
}

void sortarray(){
    // number of records a  r=a first for loop
    // inner for loop s=r+1
    struct person temp,student[10];
    int a=10;
    for (int r=0;r<a-1;r++) {
        for (int s=r+1;r<a;s++) {
            if (strcmp(student[r].name, student[s].name) > 0) {
                temp = student[r];
                student[r] =student[s];
                student[s] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @gs Gunasekara What array is being sorted by the function?!

Comment: `printf ( "%s\n Un-sorted array")` and `printf ( "%s\n Sorted array")`??? Take some time to [explain those calls to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Answer (score 2):

Besides the undefined behavior you have from two of your `printf` calls, you have a problem with local variables actually being local.

The `student` array in the `main` function is not the same `student` array in the `sortarray` function. The array in the `sortarray` function will be uninitialized and attempting to sort it will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The solution is to pass a pointer to the first element of the array from the `main` function, so the `sortarray` function can use it. That needs three changes:

1. Add a forward declaration of the `sortarray` function:

   ```
   void sortarray(struct person *);
   ```
2. Call the function passing a pointer to the first element:

   ```
   sortarray(student);  // As arrays decays to pointers, this is like passing &student[0]
   ```
3. Remove the definition of the `student` array in the `sortarray` function.